# Can't exit a "for" loop

Tags: c

I know its probably obvious issue but since in very new to C I had to ask,

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ASIZE 8
int main()

{
    int index;

    long int numbers[ASIZE];

    printf("enter 8 integers to be printed in reverse order:\n");

    for (index = 0; index < ASIZE; index++)

    {
        scanf("%li", &numbers[index]);
    }

    printf("indexing is done!");

}
```

Why am I not exiting the 'for' loop and printing "indexing is done!" ?

Comment: sorry the ASIZE is defined @Oli Charlesworth

Comment: just edited, its the size limit for the array @user droog

Comment: What are you typing as input when you run your program?  If it isn't `1 <enter> 2 <enter> 3 <enter> 4 <enter> 5 <enter> 6 <enter> 7 <enter> 8 <enter>`?

Comment: im typing 8 integers together..shouldn't in able to do that? only enter? @RichieHindle

Comment: What do you mean 'together'?  Like `12345678`?  That's just one integer.  Spaces will work for your program too.

Comment: Thank you guys, got it now! sorry for the newbie question :)

Comment: @nir: Newbie questions are fine - we were all newbies once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` requires your inputs to be whitespace-separated.  Entering `12345678` will only go once round the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will/should work provided that you have entered space, enter, tab separated inputs. If you are entering e.g. 82341679 as 8 numbers, these are not eight inputs, this is just only one input.

Answer (score 1):

You are really new to C !
Anyways, just to make things clear, your code is perfectly fine.
Input the numbers like
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

and not like 12345678, since it itself is one integer. 
Cheers!